# Matching part of a regex for addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a form validator with a custom pattern.  Here's the regex 
`^d+s[A-z]+s?[A-z]*$`

What I'd like to do is match `123 Main Street` OR `123 Main street #23`

The essential elements for a successful validation should be
1) At least 1 number at the beginning 
2) a space after the number/numbers
3) At least 1 alpha character that represents the street name.

If there's anything after that, numbers, special characters etc I still need it to validate as true.  For example, both of these should validate successfully.
`123 Main street #23 NW` or `123 Main street NW #23`

How do I do this?

Comment: javascript.  Updated my tags

Comment: Something like `^\d+ [A-Za-z]` for validation, or `^\d+ [A-Za-z].*` for extraction?

Comment: `^\d+\s+[a-zA-Z]+.*` This should be good for you to go

Comment: @Aaron: I guess you've never been to New York ;)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/OQJtXD/1/

Comment: @georg As a matter of fact I haven't. Anyway I was just trying to translate OP's requirements to a regex rather than guess what he should be doing.

Comment: @Aaron: nope. "at least 1 alpha character that represents the street name" doesn't mean that the street has to _start_ with an alpha.

Comment: @georg I understood OP's sentence as an enumeration of the successive tokens that should be matched. Are you saying OP would have wanted `^\d+ .*[A-Za-z]` ? I'm not sure that would be very useful, if you're going down that route you might as well use `^\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
^\d+\s+(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Start of string.
- `\d+` - Matches one or more number.
- `\s+` - Matches one or more space.
- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - Matches alphabet.(Condition to force at least one alphabet )
- `.*` - Matches anything except newline.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MnN49U/3)

Comment: Since this is just for validation, you can leave the `.*$` part out as it doesn't enforce any additional constraint (i.e. instead of saying "it starts with X then ends with whatever", just say "it starts with X")

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
^\d+\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+\s*[a-zA-Z\.]+(?:\s*[#0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\s*[#0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)?$
```

I included the possibility of numbers at the first part, because I remember I lived on a street named `11th street`, and I added the possibility of dots for the second part of the address for the usage of shortcuts `Street -> St.`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/N683Xq/3/

Here are some quick details:

- `[0-9A-Za-z]` were used to include any numbers or alpha.
- `(?: )` This is a non-capturing group.
- `()?` Adding question mark after () to make them optional.

Comment: `[0-z]` matches much more than digits and letters, for example `:;<=>?@` between `9` and `A` and `[\]^_\``, have a look at an ASCII table.

Comment: Your regex matches `123 <===> ]]]`, not sure it is a valid address.

Comment: Sorry but not enough ;( `[A-z]` matches letters and `[\]^_\``

Comment: Interesting, always thought `[A-z]` is a good shortcut for `[A-Za-z]`. Fixed.